# How do I style the menu items text in the Android Toolbar?

Tags: android

How can I style the menu item text with the new Android Toolbar, like you used to be able to do with `android:actionMenuTextAppearance`?

I tried using that same property in the toolbar style, and it appears not to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

For styling AppCompat toolbar popups:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <!-- your other theme overrides here -->
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/MyLargePopupStyle</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/MySmallPopupStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyLargePopupStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_popup_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MySmallPopupStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_popup_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "app" namespace:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:actionMenuTextAppearance="@style/myAppearance"
```

Comment: Never tested it, but I know you need "app" for most XML attributes about toolbar menus. It was worth trying.

Comment: (I remember android:itemTextAppearance being used somewhere, you might try that also)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the styling in the menu xml resource file?

Go to your menu resource (usually in the res/menu folder) and select which item you want to change appearance of. Then use `android:textAppearance` to set the appearance

Comment: This does not work (I tried it), and textAppearance also isn't a listed attribute of menu items either, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html